# SQL MAX function returns one row when multiple rows have the same value

Tags: sql, max

In one of my queries I have 3 rows which contain the same numerical value. When I used the MAX function on them, it returned only 1 row. My question is why does SQL ignore the other rows.

[image: Click here for the first query]

[image: Click here for the second query]

I know this isn't practical but I'm just wondering why it does this.

Any help would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: `MAX(country)` .?

Comment: Please post the queries in text and not in images.

Comment: @Chad . . . What database are you using?  Your queries would be invalid in most databases because you have a `GROUP BY` and unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows with the maximum value, then think "filtering" not "aggregation":

In addition, the `join` is not needed.  All the columns you need are in `invoice`.  So:

```
select i.*
from invoice i 
where i.invoiceTotal = (select max(i2.invoiceTotal)
                        from invoice i2
                       );
```

The reason your query returns one row is because it is an aggregation query with no `group by`.  Be definition, such a query returns *exactly* one row (even if the underlying table is empty).

You are selecting columns not in the `group by`.  That is generally an error, although some databases do (unfortunately) allow this syntax.  In any case, I suspect the above version does what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

could be you are using  a mysql version previous the 5.7 ...

in these version  mysql allo the use of aggreagtion function without mention in group by all the column in select but not in aggreation function. (this is not allowed  in mysql starting from mysql 5.7  )

In these case the result for not aggreated  values in unpredictable  .. so you should control this usi proper agggregation functiom for column not in group by

```
    select max(customer_id), country, max(total) 
    from  (
        select customer.customerId as customer_id
            ,  invoice.billingCountry as country
            , sum(invoice.total) as total
        from  invoice
        join customer on customer.cutomerId = invoice.customerId
        where invoice.billingCountry = 'United  Kingdom'
        group by 1
    ) t
    group by country
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, the second query was wrong. I shall avoid using images next time. I thought it would be clearer for you all.

Here is the second query

`SELECT Customer_ID, Country, MAX(Total)
FROM
  (SELECT customer.CustomerId AS Customer_ID,
    invoice.BillingCountry AS Country, SUM(invoice.Total) AS Total
  FROM Invoice
  JOIN Customer
  ON Customer.CustomerId = invoice.CustomerId
  WHERE invoice.BillingCountry = 'United Kingdom'
  GROUP BY Customer_ID)`

I'm using a ChinookDatabase which is just a sample database with SQLite.